# API incompatibility with SonarQube 5.6 and Java Analyzer 4.0 with Findbugs 3.3 or Cobertura 1.6.3

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

The analyzes of my projects are failing with SonarQube `5.6`, after updating the **Java Plugin** from version `3.14` to `4.0`.

In my SonarQube instance, among other plugins, I currently have the Findbugs plugin (version `3.3`) and the Cobertura plugin (`1.6.3`) which require the Java plugin.

Looking at the log, I get the following message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1-build231:sonar (default-cli) 
    on project MyProject: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1-build231:sonar failed:

    An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1-build231:sonar: 

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;

...

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor.analyse(FindbugsSensor.java:108)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    ... 20 more
```

What should I do to get my analysis not failing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Version `4.0` of the **SonarQube Java Analyzer** introduced changes in its API, in order to stay aligned with the new API of SonarQube `5.6` LTS (Long Term Support).

Unfortunately, these changes potentially broke compatibility with plugin directly relying on the Java Analyzer. If last released versions of `PMD` and `Checkstyle` plugins are not affected, version `3.3` of the `Findbugs` is unfortunately not compatible anymore, as well as version `1.6.3` of the `Cobertura` plugin.

In order to solve the issue with Findbugs, you have the following option:

- Update to version >= `3.4` of the Findbugs plugin, which is currently in **Request For Feedback** period ([see this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarqube/iB6d12tiKR0/discussion)), and should be released soon ([confirmed with version 3.4.2](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarqube/ELhd_cihir4/discussion)).
- Remove the Findbugs plugin or temporarily disable its rules.

For the Cobertura plugin, update to version >= `1.7` (requires LTS 5.6 and Java 8), which solve the issue. The update should be available using the SonarQube UI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, updating cobertura-1.7 findbugs-3.4.3 and java Analyzer-4.1 versions resolved the issue.