# SonarQube 6.0 analysis fails on module without code

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

**ENVIRONMENT**

- Jenkins 2.23
- SonarQube plugin 2.4.4
- SonarQube 6.0
- Java plugin 4.2
- Findbugs plugin 3.4.3
- Clirr 1.3
- (some other plugins, probably not relevant for this issue, but feel free to ask in the comments and I´ll edit the question)

I have a multi-module Maven project with one *root* module (pom packaging, no code) and several child modules (jar packaging, code). I´m running SonarQube analysis in a Maven job in Jenkins.

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

Analysis worked ok in SQ 5.x. Since upgrading to SQ 6.0, the analysis fails:

- the analysis on the child modules succeeds
- the analysis on the root module fails with error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on
> project root:
> org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;
> -> [Help 1]

**ALREADY TRIED**

- excluding the root module from analysis --> results in Maven error

> Unable to determine structure of project. Probably you use Maven
> Advanced Reactor Options with a broken tree of modules. "foo" is
> orphan

- Findbugs plugin 3.4.4 from https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs/releases (as hinted in [API incompatibility with SonarQube 5.6 and Java Analyzer 4.0 with Findbugs 3.3 or Cobertura 1.6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225515/api-incompatibility-with-sonarqube-5-6-and-java-analyzer-4-0-with-findbugs-3-3-o)) --> same error

**DEBUG LOGGING**

Maven with `-e` and `-X`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project root: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource; -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project root: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;
    at org.sonar.plugins.clirr.ClirrSensor.saveIssues(ClirrSensor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.clirr.ClirrSensor.analyse(ClirrSensor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:184)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:78)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 34 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**QUESTION**

Is this a configuration issue at my end? Or is there an issue with SonarQube or any of the plugins?

I will also accept answers that let me exclude the codeless root module as a workaround, without any interference for the child modules that have it as a parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines that might have raised your attention are the following ones:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator.findResourceByClassName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Resource;
    at org.sonar.plugins.clirr.ClirrSensor.saveIssues(ClirrSensor.java:94)
```

You must uninstall the Clirr plugin: it is not compatible with SonarQube 6.0.

Comment: Clirr is not compatible, or Clirr is *not yet* compatible? I have opened an issue here: https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-clirr/issues/4

Comment: Clirr is not compatible. And unless someone from the community works on github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-clirr/issues/4, it will never be.

Comment: Between the lines I am reading "fork the project, fix compatibility yourself, and submit a pull request". Correct?

Comment: Or you can ask on the Google group to become the official maintainer of the plugin, this is another possibility.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, maybe this is not exactly the solution to your problem. But let me describe where I ran into a similar problem that matches your following description:

```
Unable to determine structure of project. Probably you use Maven Advanced Reactor Options with a broken tree of modules. "foo" is orphan.
```

I had changed my maven build to ci friendly as described by maven [here](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html).
Generally, my maven build was running fine until I added sonarqube check. Then I got the above-described message. It took a while to finde the problem and it was quite tricky.

By the way, I had a multiple module maven project running and the problem was that in my parent pom I was referring to the pom.xml instead of the folder.

```
    <modules>
       <module>modules/module1</module>

       <!-- the reference to the pom.xml is the problem.
            and will cause sonar to fail -->
       <module>modules/module2/pom.xml</module>
    </modules>
```

Comment: No, that's not it. The answer from 6 years ago, from Fabrice (a SonarQube Team member), was correct. Clirr simply wasn't compatible.